# CakePHP: hasOne relationship returns null for fields

Tags: php, cakephp, has-one

I have 2 models, `Venue` and `Contact`, where 1 venue has 1 contact, but 1 contact can be responsible for many venues. In my tables, `venue.contactid` references the column `contact.id`

My models look like this:

```
class Contact extends AppModel {  
public $useTable = 'contact';
public $belongsTo = [
        'Contact'=>[
                'className'=>'Venue',
                'foreignKey'=>'contactid',
                'conditions'=>['Contact.id  = Venue.contactid']
        ]];
}
class Venue extends AppModel {  

public $useTable = "venue";
public $hasOne = [
        'Contact'=>[
                'className'=>'Contact',
                'foreignKey'=>'id',
                'conditions'=>['Venue.contactid = Contact.id']
        ]];
}
```

The problem is that, when I retrieve the Venue, the `Contact` field has everything set to `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
class Contact extends AppModel {  
    public $useTable = 'contact';
    public $hasMany = [ // Has many, you said it
        'Venue'=> [ // Venue here, not Contact
            'className'=>'Venue',
            'foreignKey'=>'contactid'
        ] // No need of conditions, you don't have anything special
    ]; 
}

class Venue extends AppModel {  

    public $useTable = "venue";
    public $belongsTo = [ // the contactid is in the venue table, it's a belongsTo not a hasOne
        'Contact' => [
            'className'=>'Contact',
            'foreignKey'=>'contactid'
        ]
    ];
}
```

You made some mistakes between `hasOne` and `belongsTo` and other relationships, have a look here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html.

Anyway, you should try to keep CakePHP convention to simplify your code. If you change your field `contactid` to `contact_id` and add an `s` to your table names, your code becomes:

```
class Contact extends AppModel {  
    public $hasMany = ['Venue'] ;
}

class Venue extends AppModel {  
    public $belongsTo = ['Contact'] ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try these when I get back to work. I'm new to CakePHP and I inherited the database from a previous developer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Code like this.

```
class Contact extends AppModel {  
     public $useTable = 'contact';
     public $belongsTo = [
      'Venue'=>[
            'className'=>'Venue',
            'foreignKey'=>'contactid',
            'conditions'=>['Venue.contactid  =  Contact.id' ]
      ]];
}
```

Comment: I made the change but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Did you check with $hasMany Relation ?